# Film, friends transferred to a parallel universe where being fat is forbidden, one of them meets his "alternate world" wife

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

The movie starts with a man in a basement with his dog, and then he transfers his dog to a parallel universe, and then the dog comes back. Then two friends come to visit him in the basement, and then the door transfers again but they don't go back. So the two friends are transferred after the dog, to where they can meet themselves there (but not the same) and since it's not safe to meet themselves, they need to come back in the same day.

But then, there one of the friends meets his wife, that is his wife there, but he died in a war on this world. The other man is a doctor in a hospital in this world, who has something implanted in his head. The last one is a fat man, and the police are after him since fat people not allowed to be in public.

At some point in the movie the fat man is forced to move to the forest out of the city where all the fat people are.

The other one falls in love with his wife in this world.

The last one finds out he should play in a game (a TV game) where everyone is after him to kill him, and then he runs away.

I also remember that in the parallel universe all the cars were white and the same model, and everyone can drive a car that is free.

Comment: _"But then one of the friends meets there his wife that in his wife there but he died in a war on this world. The other one is a doctor in hospital, but in this world he planet ppl something in the head."_ I'm not sure I get what you mean there. Does he have a bomb in his skull or something? And he's not supposed to be in this world with his wife?

Comment: Also - you tagged this with [time-travel] but where's the time travel here? Is the other universe in the past/future? What year would this have been released, more or less? Did you watch it in English? Lots of questions I know, but the more info you give us, the more likely you are to get "the" answer :)

Comment: There is no bomb in the skull in the real world he was working in hospital as head surgery in the parallel world he died in a war desert war but in the hospital he worked now they make head surgery that put something behind on the neck or head that make the ppl act different. No in this parallel world he died in desert storm war but when he see his wife as widow he try to meet her and tell her he didn't die and there was identify mistake of his body.

Comment: The time travel is in the start the movie start where one of the friends with eye glasses and his dog in the basement and then he send first time his dog as a test on some plata on the floor. Then the dog return and the two friend coming to the basement and then he send them to see how it is but warning them that they should not meet them self.

Comment: In the parallel world all the card are white and same model and anyone can take a car and drive. And when he finish driving someone else can take the car and drive.

Answer (score 5):

The film in question is undoubtedly "[Tempting Fate](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137156/?ref_=nv_sr_5)".

> A man who is still mourning the death of the woman he loves, meets a man who says he created a machine that can bring anyone to a parallel world. He goes and sees the woman he loves is still alive in that world and wants to stay. But when he discovers that this world has rules that differ from his world, he wants to leave but when he goes back to where the machine is, there's a fire and the machine is destroyed and the man who built it is killed. He later meets a woman from his world who also built a machine of her own but the officials there upon seeing her thinks she's crazy because her counterpart is alive and says she doesn't know her. So he tries to help her so that they can return home.

### Movie excerpt

Comment: This one was easy.  I actually found the movie on DVD in the cheapie rack at my local grocer a couple of months ago.  Bought it to kill an afternoon, so all I had to do was check my stack and there it was.